# Common Language Runtime exceptions trapping

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7.1, invalidoperationexception

I hope someone on StackOverflow would help me out with the following problem:

I have a WP7.1 project, that I open using VS2012. Also, I have enable Common Language Runtime Exceptions. By doing this I wanted to catch and fix most bugs that I may have in the code.

When running the project in the emulator I get the following exceptions:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException occurred
  Message=TargetInvocationException
  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] index, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
       at System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.get_Value()
       at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToPropertyInSource(Boolean isSourceCollectionViewCurrentItem)
       at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToProperty()
       at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ReConnect(Object newSource)
       at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReConnect(Object source)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TargetLoaded(Object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message=InvalidOperationException
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.Duration.get_TimeSpan()
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] index, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
            at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
            at System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.get_Value()
            at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToPropertyInSource(Boolean isSourceCollectionViewCurrentItem)
            at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToProperty()
            at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ReConnect(Object newSource)
            at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReConnect(Object source)
            at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
            at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TargetLoaded(Object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
            at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
            at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

And

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  Message=InvalidOperationException
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Duration.get_TimeSpan()
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalGetValue(PropertyInfo thisProperty, Object obj, Object[] index, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
       at System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.get_Value()
       at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToPropertyInSource(Boolean isSourceCollectionViewCurrentItem)
       at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ConnectToProperty()
       at System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.ReConnect(Object newSource)
       at System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReConnect(Object source)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TargetLoaded(Object o, RoutedEventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex,
 String eventName)
```

Apparently both exceptions are linked, since they are throw one after another and contain the same inner exception.

On the page that these exceptions are thrown, I use the WPToolkit plus some custom controls. Just LoopingSelector uses the Duration structure. But I see nothing wrong the code of the LoopingSelector.

Could somebody point in which direction to look for bugs? XAML Bindings? Casting?

Comment: Are you binding anything to a TimeSpan or Duration property?

Comment: That's an error in the binding, can't say much more. You may be able to find more information in the output window (an error message is usually displayed there when a binding fails)

Comment: Inside my xaml I am binding the SSME.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan value to a Slider.Maximum property. But the TimeSpan passes through a Converter that converts the TimeSpan to a properly formatted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was able to find out a way around this issue.

In some cases the **SSME.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan** can be null. For those cases the **NaturalDuration** property has a flag **HasTimeSpan**, which returns false when the TimeSpan value cannot be retrieved.

So, I moved the binding logic to code behind. I check for **SSME.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan** always before setting a binding.